# calculation using date range is not giving output in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

My php script is taking two dates from a form and trying to get the profit calculation between these two dates.

My profit table in mysql are :id(int),order_profit(float) and order_date(date)

the form date field names are **date_from** and **date_to**

The code for the php script below:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$from_date=$_POST['date_from'];
$to_date=$_POST['date_to'];
echo "Small date : ".$from_date."<br>";
echo "Large date : ".$to_date;

    $count=1;


 $queryA=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(order_profit) FROM profit  WHERE profit_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE($from_date, '%Y/%m/%d') AND STR_TO_DATE($to_date, '%Y/%m/%d') ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryA)){
        $count++;

         echo "Total Profit"." =". $row['SUM(order_profit)'];
      }
    echo $count;    
           echo "<br />";


?>
```

when the outcome shows it displays two dates and count value 2. That means the while loop body is executed once but no profit value is shown.But no error is shown.

Please help me in this regard

Comment: Check that the str_to_date in the query is working properly. It could be converting wrong or returning null to indicate failure, which "breaks" the query.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're using the correct column name:

```
var_dump($row);
```

Or name it explicitly:

```
SELECT SUM(order_profit) as sum
```

Comment: ... and finally find your result in `$row['sum'];`

Comment: sum is a registered word, thus it cannot be used as a variable name. also the dates must be enquoted. check out my answer.

Comment: would you please write down the code for profit sum of the date range.

Answer (score 0):

You can also echo your SQL query and run it in your SQL editor to see what it's actually returning.  I've had a number of untraceable php issues that were resolved by checking if my query was valid.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. IMHO dates must be be enquoted. Check also the mysql errors in case there are some: mysql_error() is your friend.

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$query = "SELECT SUM(order_profit) as profitsum FROM profit ";
$query .= "WHERE profit_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['date_from']."', '%Y/%m/%d') ";
$query .= "AND STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['date_to']."', '%Y/%m/%d')";

// to check the query
echo $query ."<br/>";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "Total Profit: ".$row['profitsum']."<br/>;

?>
```

Comment: thank you so much...it is working properly...a great relief for me